# Unwanted error message when running puppet agent on Solaris

Tags: puppet

When I run the puppet agent to fetch catalogue from the puppet master its giving below error message though the puppet agent is executed properly.

```
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: user 20170818-18082-9pyaem doesn't exist
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: user 20170818-18082-9pyaem doesn't exist
Wrapped exception:
user 20170818-18082-9pyaem doesn't exist
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/~]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: user 20170818-18082-9pyaem doesn't exist
```

Whenever I run puppet agent the value "`20170818-18082-9pyaem`" in the above is output is keep changing and not sure from where this is coming. Below are the files available in the folder /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/.

```
root@test-server:~# ls -l /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         390 Jul 25 00:35 apt_package_updates.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         295 Jul 25 00:35 apt_security_updates.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         286 Jul 25 00:35 apt_updates.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         212 Jul 25 00:36 concat_basedir.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        4637 Jul 25 00:35 facter_dot_d.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         218 Jul 25 06:39 gemhome.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         139 Jul 25 00:35 httpd_running.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         236 Jul 25 00:35 ip6tables_version.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         444 Jul 25 00:35 iptables_persistent_version.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         234 Jul 25 00:36 iptables_version.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         427 Jul 25 06:39 lib_process_running.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        1172 Jul 25 00:35 pe_version.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         937 Jul 25 00:35 puppet_vardir.rb
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           3 Jul 25 00:35 util
root@test-server:~#
```

Can anybody provide some suggestion to fix or identify from where this error is coming.

Update 1:

Debug output,

```
Debug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'confdir': 'File[/etc/puppet]{:path=>"/etc/puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Failed to load library 'shadow' for feature 'libshadow'
Debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUseradd: file chage does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/uuidgen does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
Debug: /User[puppet]: Provider user_role_add does not support features libuser; not managing attribute forcelocal
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
Debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
Debug: /Group[puppet]: Provider groupadd does not support features libuser; not managing attribute forcelocal
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'vardir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'logdir': 'File[/var/log/puppet]{:path=>"/var/log/puppet", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state", :mode=>"1755", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rundir': 'File[/var/run/puppet]{:path=>"/var/run/puppet", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'libdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/lib", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'certdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'ssldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl", :mode=>"771", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'publickeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'requestdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatekeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostcert': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/test.server.com.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/test.server.com.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostprivkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/test.server.com.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/test.server.com.pem", :mode=>"640", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostpubkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/test.server.com.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/test.server.com.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'localcacert': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostcrl': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statefile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml", :mode=>"660", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientyamldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'client_datadir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_data", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'classfile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/classes.txt]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/classes.txt", :mode=>"640", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'resourcefile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt", :mode=>"640", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientbucketdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunfile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml", :mode=>"644", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunreport': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml", :mode=>"640", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'graphdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'pluginfactdest': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/facts.d", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/test.server.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/test.server.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/test.server.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/classes.txt]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: Finishing transaction 11123916
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'confdir': 'File[/etc/puppet]{:path=>"/etc/puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'vardir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'logdir': 'File[/var/log/puppet]{:path=>"/var/log/puppet", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state", :mode=>"1755", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rundir': 'File[/var/run/puppet]{:path=>"/var/run/puppet", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'libdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/lib", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'certdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'ssldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl", :mode=>"771", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'publickeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'requestdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatekeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostcert': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/test.server.com.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/test.server.com.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostprivkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/test.server.com.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/test.server.com.pem", :mode=>"640", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostpubkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/test.server.com.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/test.server.com.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'localcacert': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostcrl': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'pluginfactdest': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/facts.d", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/test.server.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/test.server.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/test.server.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: Finishing transaction 12444336
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Using cached certificate for test.server.com
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statefile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml", :mode=>"660", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientyamldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'client_datadir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_data", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'classfile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/classes.txt]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/classes.txt", :mode=>"640", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'resourcefile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt", :mode=>"640", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientbucketdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunfile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml", :mode=>"644", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunreport': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml", :mode=>"640", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'graphdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Finishing transaction 12947400
Debug: Loaded state in 0.01 seconds
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: node supports formats: pson b64_zlib_yaml yaml raw
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Using cached certificate for test.server.com
Debug: Using cached certificate_revocation_list for ca
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson b64_zlib_yaml yaml raw
Debug: Finishing transaction 14046708
Info: Retrieving plugin
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson b64_zlib_yaml yaml raw
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: user 20170818-22623-1gm6w6c doesn't exist
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: user 20170818-22623-1gm6w6c doesn't exist
Wrapped exception:
user 20170818-22623-1gm6w6c doesn't exist
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/~]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: user 20170818-22623-1gm6w6c doesn't exist
Debug: Finishing transaction 1564008
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/iptables_persistent_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/ip6tables_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/gemhome.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/iptables_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/httpd_running.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/apt_updates.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/lib_process_running.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/apt_package_updates.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/apt_security_updates.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: catalog supports formats: pson b64_zlib_yaml yaml dot raw
Info: Caching catalog for test.server.com
```

Comment: Run the code with `--debug` to help you find out which piece of manifest code is adding the file, and show us that code.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I have updated the debug details

Answer (score 0):

It says below user doesnt exist .

user 20170818-18082-9pyaem

Can you please check whether you are creating file and setting ownership to some user .?

If yes , you need to create that user and then set the ownership

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue. Found that under lib folder on one of the puppet module there is a folder ~ created which I deleted it. Thanks!